# Separate a string and place in array

Tags: c#

How can I split this string and place in into an array can it be by a break line or new lines

This is the api url

```
 https://stats.nba.com/stats/draftcombinenonstationaryshooting https://stats.nba.com/stats/draftcombinenonstationaryshooting https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoreplayertrackv2
```

I tried using but the string place it in index 0

```
     string[] lines = split.Split(
                new[] { Environment.NewLine },
                StringSplitOptions.None
            );
```

I would like to get each individual link from the string and store in an array

Source link: any-api.com

Comment: I don't see any new lines in the source string, there are spaces only.

Comment: Split it using spaces.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the parameters of split. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) and then follow crimson's advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also call [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) without any arguments, in which case it will split on whitespace characters, so your sample code can simply be reduced to:

```
string[] lines = split.Split();
```

Comment: Just a note - this will add empty elements in array if there are multiple spaces between values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = urlString.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This ensures there are no blank elements in `array` if URLs are separated by multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo for you, you can try it.

```
string urlString = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/draftcombinenonstationaryshooting https://stats.nba.com/stats/draftcombinenonstationaryshooting https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoreplayertrackv2";
var array = urlString.Split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can easily use the **Regex** like this:

```
string data = " https://stats.nba.com/stats/draftcombinenonstationaryshooting https://stats.nba.com/stats/draftcombinenonstationaryshooting https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoreplayertrackv2";
string regex = @"\s";
string[] result = Regex.Split(data.Trim(), regex);
```

Comment: This is about 4.96x slower than Nikhil's answer in my benchmark tests (10,000 iterations, 1000 space-separated "test" in the string). Yours ran in 8302ms, Nikhil's in 1675ms.

Comment: @John Thank you for your effort on this!